# Why does `sudo env "PATH=$PATH"` do anything at all?

Tags: environment-variables, path, sudo

Can anybody explain why this:

```
sudo env "PATH=$PATH" make install
```

is not the same as this:

```
sudo make install
```

?

I had a situation recently where `make install` failed unless run as shown above. The error had something to do with libtool, but that's sort of besides the point - why does `sudo env "PATH=$PATH"` do anything whatsoever? Shouldn't `PATH` already be in the environment from my shell session?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's normal for `sudo` to ignore the `PATH` it got in the environment.

When you run `sudo some_command`, `sudo` uses its own set of directories instead of `PATH`. This set may or may not be defined somewhere in `sudo` config (`/etc/sudoers`, `/etc/sudoers.d/*`). If it's not explicitly defined, `/etc/sudoers` says the default value is

```
secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
```

(This is somewhat simplified, other options may alter this mechanics; see `man 5 sudoers` for details).

Not only `sudo` uses its own `PATH` to locate executables; also commands run by `sudo` inherit this other `PATH`, not your original `PATH` from the shell.

`env foo=bar baz` is a way to set the variable `foo` to the value of `bar` for the command `baz`. When you do

> ```
> sudo env "PATH=$PATH" make install
> ```

the shell expands `$PATH`. `sudo` resets the variable for `env`, but `env` gets your old expanded value inside the `PATH=…` command line argument. This way you inject your `PATH` into the environment of `make`, circumventing the fact `sudo` changes `PATH` (still the other value of `PATH` matters elsewhere: `sudo` uses it to search for `env` executable in the first place).

You may be able to achieve a similar result with

```
sudo "PATH=$PATH" make install
```

but variables passed this way are subjects to restrictions imposed by the security policy plugin for `sudo`. What you did with `env` is not restricted.

---

Compare outputs from these (note sole `env` prints its environment):

```
export foo=bar
                         env | grep '^foo='
             env foo=qux env | grep '^foo='
sudo                     env | grep '^foo='
sudo foo=baz             env | grep '^foo='
sudo         env foo=qux env | grep '^foo='
sudo foo=baz env foo=qux env | grep '^foo='
```

Another set to compare:

```
                      env | grep '^PATH='
sudo                  env | grep '^PATH='
sudo     "PATH=$PATH" env | grep '^PATH='
sudo env "PATH=$PATH" env | grep '^PATH='
```

In general, depending on your `PATH` and settings of `sudo` the results may or may not be identical. In your case I expect them to differ (because the two commands in question worked differently).